# Using Externalizable in Apache Ignite

Tags: jakarta-ee, ignite

I have 4 doubts,

1. My model classes are externalizable. Still they can be queried using 
   SQLFieldsQuery at server node without any problem right?
2. Externalizable items cannot be queried from a client node in remote, 
   right? Is there a way to make it happen at client ?
3. Does using externalizable affect clustering data between nodes in any way?
4. Are there any other limitations using externalizable or any performance 
   concerns?

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes, you still can query your objects.
2. You can query it from client as well as from server.
3. `AffinityFunction` uses key to calculate hash and get proper partition. So result depends on writeExternal/readExternal implementations, and that means key distribution could be changed between partitions.
4. Yes, it's always a bad idea to use `Externalizable`.

First of all Ignite will use `OptimizedMarshaller` that is slower and produces bigger objects than `BinaryMarshaller` that is used by default.

Second, Ignite on `SQLFieldsQuery` reads only specific fields from binary object representation. In case of `Externalizable`, it has to de-serialize whole object to read it's fields. So, such choice has negative performance impact.

You may additionally use [Binarylizable](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/binary/Binarylizable.html) interface. In that case `BinaryMarshaller` will be used.